# What should I do if Django doesn't send any email when I requested?

Tags: python, django, django-email

I was trying to make the custom password reset view for `django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset`.

I made it by myself (Of course, I see some tutorial articles.)
But when I request the password reset form to the development server,
It shows like this (on the development server log):

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Hello
From: <My email address> (Outlook)
To: <My another email address> (GMail)
Date: Wed, 22 Aug 2018 11:44:55 -0000
Message-ID: <20180822114455.3320.17387@Yeonhos-MacBook-Pro.local>
I am testing Django EmailMessage Class
```

But, It doesn't send anything to my address which is marked as `My another email address`.
Can anyone help me? Why doesn't Django send this e-mail?

Comment: Where is that being shown?

Comment: Please share your code where you are trying to send email. Are you using any  api to send email?

Comment: I am not using any API, just I am using django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset view, and it is being shown in the development server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using G mail, you need to enable 2FA(2 Factor Authentication) and go to App passwords setting. Then you can generate app password, and you must put that password into Django settings.py like this:

```
#settings.py
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'YOUR_GMAIL_ADDRESS'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'YOUR_APP_PASSWORD'
```

It worked for me :)
See this article for how to generate app password and use it for django:
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/free-smtp-server/
(You can skip step 4)

Answer (score 0):

If you're following along a tutorial, then it's possible you have the console email backend configured, which is only useful for debugging - look for this line in your settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

To actually send mail, you'll have to configure Django to use the SMTP backend and you'll also need details for a mailserver which will allow you access. To use the SMTP backend replace the line above with the following:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = '...'  # Your mailserver host
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '...'  # Your mailserver user, if required
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '...'  # Your mailserver password, if required
```

Comment: Oh I should try it

Comment: As I said, you'll need to find a mailserver which will let you send email - GMail probably doesn't provide public access. 

If you're on a company or school network, you could ask your local sysadmin if they have a mailserver that employees/students can use.